# arduino serial monitor shows no value

Tags: arduino, rfid

I have interfaced EM-18 RFID module with Arduino uno, and it had worked well. But now the same code and connections doesn't giving me output in the serial monitor. Can someone help me!!!

The code is as follows;

```
#include<SoftwareSerial.h>
SoftwareSerial mySerial(9,10);
int read_count=0,tag_count=0;
int j=0,k=0; // Variabvles to iterate in for loops
char data_temp, RFID_data[12], data_store[10][12];
boolean disp_control;

void setup()
{
mySerial.begin(9600);
Serial.begin(9600);
}

void loop()
{
RecieveData();
StoreData();
PrintData();
}

void RecieveData()
{
if(mySerial.available()>0)
{
data_temp=mySerial.read();
RFID_data[read_count]=data_temp;
read_count++;
}
}

void StoreData()
{

if(read_count==12)
{
disp_control=true;  
for(k=tag_count;k<=tag_count;k++)
{
for(j=0;j<12;j++)
{
data_store[k][j]=RFID_data[j];
}
}
read_count=0;
tag_count++;
}
}

void PrintData()
{
if(disp_control==true)
{
  for(k=0;k<=tag_count;k++)
{
    for(j=0;j<12;j++)
  {
    Serial.write(data_store[k][j]);
  }
  Serial.println();
}
disp_control=false;
}
}
```

**I have checked the port and corrected it .But it doesn't worked for me**

Comment: and the baud rate setting in Serial Monitor?

Comment: I have checked it also. But no change in serial monitor